# Tips about conjugation

Tags: conjugaison

Am a totaly new learner. I am finding it very difficult to conjugate verbs. Any tips on how best to learn how to understand conjugation?

Comment: Read, and write, as much French as you can. There aren't any shortcuts.

Edit: Also, this book is indispensable for reference and is owned by every school-age person in France: http://www.amazon.com/Bescherelle-Conjugaison-Pour-French-Edition/dp/2218951983

Comment: Whilst there are irregularities, there are patterns too, and you will learn to get the 'feel' of them.

Comment: There are three verb groups, learn the basic terminations of the specific groups (terminaisons).

Comment: il faut connaitre le présent, passé, l'imparfait et le futur le coditionnel, ça suffit pour comprendre 95% communication. de toute maniere au bout de six mois il faut réaprendre tout les mots qui sont peut employé.